# Highcharts column w/ overlapping goal

Tags: highcharts

I am in need to see if the following is possible.  I have a current top 10 chart that displays the sales for the top ten stores.  I am being tasked with adding functionality to address individual store goals.

What I need to know is if Highcharts will allow me to show the current column for the store and then somehow (preferably with an overlapping column) goal percentage.

As an added kick is it possible to do this from an HTML table?  If not I'll have to figure out how to convert my current set up to load it with data.

Image shown for greater clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you can't mix percentage values with true values - just calculate percents to value.

To get overlapped columns, set `grouping: false` see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.grouping).

And for HTML table.. use official plugin for Highcharts to get this done, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/SnLFj/ (docs are inside data.src.js file)